# isotope packery layout ideal item sizes

Tags: layout, jquery-isotope, packery

I am trying to make a nice layout of items in a grid using a bin packing algorithm like packery or masonry. I  Already have isotope installed so will use the packery plugin for that.

If you look at the example here http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/vdwmb this is exactly the kind of thing I need, but the problem I think I'm going to face is the content of the items are via a CMS.

```
<h1>Isotope - packery layout mode</h1>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #0D8;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.7);
}

.grid-item--width2 { width: 200px; }
.grid-item--height2 { height: 200px; }

$('.grid').isotope({
  layoutMode: 'packery',
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
```

Possibly more of a maths question, but Im assuming for packery to work the items all have to be of a size in relation to each other, ie in the example above all the items are multiples of the smallest item.

Is this assumption correct, and is there anything else i need to consider?

Comment: I believe you mean the paging. Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Paging is a concept used in programming, denoting the phenomenon when there is a data of n units, where n might be very large and it is divided into partitions, or pages of k length, meaning that the first partition would be the first k element, the second partition would be the second k element and so on.